# pull specific data from broken json in database, using redshift

Tags: sql, json, regex, amazon-redshift

so I have table source that 1 important column is broken json. below is the sample of the data

```
event_properties
"{\"source\":\"barcode\",\"voucher_id\":684883298,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 1\"}"
"{\"entryPoint\":\"voucher_selection-popup\",\"entry_point\":\"voucher_selection-popup\",\"source\":\"mobile\",\"voucher_id\":712001960,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 2\"}"
"{\"source\":\"barcode\",\"voucher_id\":638584138,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 1\"}"
"{\"source\":\"QR Static\",\"voucher_id\":642124374,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 3\"}"
```

each line represent the 1 record. is there a way to extract the voucher id and voucher_name information since there are more than 1 variation in the data.

so the goal is to extract the voucher id and voucher name like this

```
voucher_id   voucher_name
684883298    voucher 1
712001960    voucher 2
638584138    voucher 1
642124374    voucher 3
```

im using redshift

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. first verify if the JSON is valid with `is_valid_json()`.
2. if not, inspect what is required to make it valid, in this case by removing leading and trailing `"`.
3. in this scenario, use `trim()` to remove the redundant `"` chars.
4. use `json_extract_path_text()` to obtain values.

SQL:

```
with json_data as (
select '"{\"source\":\"barcode\",\"voucher_id\":684883298,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 1\"}"'::text as j union
select '"{\"entryPoint\":\"voucher_selection-popup\",\"entry_point\":\"voucher_selection-popup\",\"source\":\"mobile\",\"voucher_id\":712001960,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 2\"}"'::text union
select '"{\"source\":\"barcode\",\"voucher_id\":638584138,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 1\"}"'::text union
select '"{\"source\":\"QR Static\",\"voucher_id\":642124374,\"voucher_name\":\"voucher 3\"}"'::text)
select j,
       is_valid_json(j),
       trim('"' from j) as j_trimmed,
       is_valid_json(j_trimmed),
       json_extract_path_text(j_trimmed, 'voucher_id') as voucher_id
from json_data;
```

Yields the `voucher_id` values. Then use the same method to get the other keys' values.